# Why is 1Password 7 not deleting from my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, finder, launchpad, 1password

I have installed 1Password 7 onto my MacBook Pro running MacOS Mojave to try it out. I didn't really like the application so I decided to delete my account and delete the app. According to the App Store and Finder, the app was deleted:

[image: Here is a screenshot of 1Password displayed as deleted and ready to download again in the Apple Mac App Store.]

Launchpad, however, still shows the application is still on my Mac, even though it cannot be opened:

[image: This is a screenshot of 1Password still showing up on my Launchpad, unable to be opened.]

I even checked the see if there were any leftover folders in Finder and followed the directions on 1Passwords support site to completely delete the application.

Why is the app still on my Launchpad even if it is really deleted and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates a broken link left behind after it was removed. Navigate to your Applications folder (Finder top bar -> go to -> Applications) and attempt to remove the dead shortcut from there. You may need a reboot to remove it from Launchpad